# CoreBluetooth: didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic throwing 'Unknown Error'

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am attempting to convert a BLE project over to using Notifications instead of polling.  I am using a Broadcom BCM20736 for the device and connecting to either my MBP(Yosemite) or iPhone 5(iOS8.1.2).

I can happily discover the peripheral and discover characteristics. The problem is that when I attempt to subscribe to notifications, I am always getting an error thrown of "Unknown Error", code below.

```
//Subscribe to any characteristic that is configured for Notifications
if (characteristic.properties & CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify)
{
    [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
}
```

For the characteristics in question, in didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService when I dump the CBCharacteristicProperties, they have the following properties:

```
Discovered Characteristic - 6606AB42-89D5-4A00-A8CE-4EB5E1414EE0
CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse
CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite
CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify
CBCharacteristicPropertyIndicate
```

I suspect that the characteristic properties may be misconfigured, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT#1:
After some additional digging on the Device side, it looks like the characteristics were configured as long characteristics AND with notifications enabled, which are not allowed in the component we are using.